# How to call different directive templates based on different kinds of objects in collection?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This code uses a directive to display customers in a collection:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/kj4oj1aa/2

the collection:

```
$scope.customers = [
    {'kind':'internal', 'firstName':'Jim', 'lastName':'Thompson', 'age':'34', 'internalcode':'X3434'},
    {'kind':'external', 'firstName':'James', 'lastName':'Hankerton', 'age':'33','website':'http://google.com'},
    {'kind':'undefined', 'firstName':'Greg', 'lastName':'Garland', 'age':'28'},
    {'kind':'external', 'firstName':'Eddie', 'lastName':'Eddington', 'age':'33','website':'http://yahoo.com'},
    {'kind':'internal', 'firstName':'Rachael', 'lastName':'Rosters', 'age':'34', 'internalcode':'X1112'},
    {'kind':'undefined', 'firstName':'David', 'lastName':'Dielan', 'age':'37'},
    {'kind':'undefined', 'firstName':'Howard', 'lastName':'Honduras', 'age':'45'}
];
```

In my directive, I am currently always calling the `itemMenuTemplateUndefined` template:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        datasource: '=',
        add: '&'
    },
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: 'itemMenuTemplateUndefined'
};
```

which calls this template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemMenuTemplateUndefined">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Age: {{item.age}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

However, from my directive, I want to call different templates based on if the **customer.kind** = `internal`, `external` or `undefined`,

e.g. the template for **internal** customers:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemMenuTemplateInternal">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>Age: {{item.age}}</div>
                <div>Internal Code: {{item.internalcode}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and the template for **external** customers:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemMenuTemplateExternal">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index">
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>Age: {{item.age}}</div>
                <div>Website: {{item.website}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**Where do I put the logic so that the directive can decide which template to display based on `customer.kind`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-include`with something like this:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        datasource: '=',
        add: '&'
    },
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
             // add here your logic and return the relative path
        };
    },
};
```

Here is the solution I would adopt for your case: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/cushuh6k/)

Comment: How do I pass in `item` so I can check `item.kind`? http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/kj4oj1aa/3/

Comment: ok, figured it out :-) `'<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index"><div ng-include="getTemplateUrl(item)"></div></div>'`

Comment: Yes that's ok because you `ng-repeat` inside the loaded directive template, so you have to handle it in the template not in the directive.

Comment: Ok, so now this works but it is iterating through the ng-repeat for each item, and so it is showing the items repetitively far too many times (http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/kj4oj1aa/4/), how can I move this logic so that it stays in the directive but only executes on each item?

Comment: One possibility is you could group by `kind` your collection and then loop it and assign the correct template to the relative grouped items so basically you loop once the kinds in the link function assigning the right template and then ng-repeat the right items in the right template

Comment: yes, but the task that I need to solve is to iterate through a collection in whatever order it comes in, displaying each template based on one of the fields, this would be simple if done in PHP or JavaScript, I'm just trying to find the syntax/procedure within the philosophy of Angular's clear separation of view / viewModel logic, certain there is a way, I suspect it includes your idea with `ng-include` so that gives me something to Google :-)

Comment: So I think it's better to ng-repeat the items creating an item-menu directive for each one instead looping them into the template.

Comment: Ok, I came up with this pragmatic solution, only one template but using `ng-switch` to show various HTML/Angular views based on `customer.kind`: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/kj4oj1aa/6/